# Why is jQuery fullCalendar not displayed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use fullcalendar and it keeps throwing this error. I have all the required files included which are:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fullcalendar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fullcalendar.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
```

And to display the calendar, I have written the following code in a JSP file.

```
   <div id="calendar"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 calendarEvent();
});

function calendarEvent(eventData){
 $("#calender").html("");
 var date = new Date();
 var d = date.getDate();
 var m = date.getMonth();
 var y = date.getFullYear();
 var calendar = $('#calender').fullCalendar({
  header: {
   left: "",
   center: "title",
//    right: "month,basicWeek,basicDay"
   right: "today prev,next"
   },
   editable: true,
   titleFormat: {
   month: "yyyy년 MMMM",
   week: "[yyyy] MMM dd일{ [yyyy] MMM dd일}",
   day: "yyyy년 MMM d일 dddd"
   },
   allDayDefault: false,
   defaultView: "month",
   editable: false,
   monthNames: ["1월","2월","3월","4월","5월","6월","7월","8월","9월","10월","11월","12월"],
   monthNamesShort: ["1월","2월","3월","4월","5월","6월","7월","8월","9월","10월","11월","12월"],
   dayNames: ["日","月","火","水","木","金","土"],
   dayNamesShort: ["日","月","火","水","木","金","土"],
   buttonText: {
   today : "오늘",
   month : "월별",
   week : "주별",
   day : "일별",
   },
   events : eventData,
   timeFormat : "HH:mm",
 });
</script>
```

However, the calendar is not displayed and an error occurs.

The error code is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'localeData' of undefined
at s (fullcalendar.min.js:1)
at i (fullcalendar.min.js:1)
at Object.defineProperty.value (fullcalendar.min.js:1)
at e (fullcalendar.min.js:1)
at Object.defineProperty.value (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
at e (fullcalendar.min.js:1)
at Object.defineProperty.value (fullcalendar.min.js:4)
at e (fullcalendar.min.js:1)
at Object.defineProperty.value (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
at e (fullcalendar.min.js:1)
```

Why do I get this error? jQuery As a beginner, I have a lot of questions.

Please tell me the solution.

Comment: What is the JavaScript code for initialising the calendar?

Comment: You haven't included the part of the code that's likely causing the issue to be thrown, which is the initialization of the calendar. Please edit your question to include this bit of code. That being said, if I were a guessing man, I'd say that you likely didn't wrap your initialization in a page-load handler, and thus the element you're trying to "calendarize" doesn't exist at the time of initialization. **EDIT:** I see a different issue now that you've posted the code. Commented below.

Comment: Please check the modified code. @jeff

Comment: Please check the modified code @Santi

Comment: Your calendar initialization function  uses the parameter `eventData` to pass events to the calendar. However, you didn't include this parameter when calling the function.

Comment: did you try to load `jQuery` before `fullCalendar` ?

Comment: I have already copied the code to test fullCalendar. How do you work to work as you say? @Santi

Comment: Please read the [Basic Usage](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/) - As others have pointed out, the plugin depends on jQuery and moment, therefore it must be included *after* jQuery and moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried loading jquery first on the html `<script>` tags?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fullcalendar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fullcalendar.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Per the [Basic Usage](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/), you'll likely need to move `moment` before `fullcalendar` as well.

Comment: Tranks for fixing the typo @Santi

Comment: I will proceed as you advised. @Santi

Comment: @Santi As you work on your advice, the error is definitely gone, but the script will fail. But what javascript code should be written to display fullCalendar?

Comment: @Santi Can you chat with me 1:1 ?

Answer (score 2):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'localeData' of undefined

Please switch the order of the imports. Try loading jquery and moment before you load fullcalendar.

Comment: Load jQuery first? I don't know what it means,

Comment: @Seongwon-Choi `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>` must come **last**.